# Unmet dependencies when installing Melodic on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, ubuntu, ubuntu-bionic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When running: `sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full`

I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-melodic-desktop-full : Depends: ros-melodic-desktop but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-perception but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-simulators but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: ros-melodic-urdf-sim-tutorial but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I have followed the instructions here: http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

I am running Ubuntu 18.04

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/299260/unmet-dependencies-when-installing-melodic-on-ubuntu-18.04/) by [apache8080](https://answers.ros.org/users/36118/apache8080/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-01**:
Do you have Gazebo installed from the osrf repositories by any chance?

> When running: `sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock`

don't you mean "after running .."? That command only deletes a file, it does not ask `apt` to install any packages.

**Comment by [apache8080](https://answers.ros.org/users/36118/apache8080/) on 2018-08-01**:
I accidentally put the wrong command in my question. I have now updated it.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-02**:
But did you install Gazebo sometime earlier and from the OSRF repositories?

**Comment by [dslowik](https://answers.ros.org/users/48092/dslowik/) on 2019-10-27**:
Use aptitude as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45335914/ros-installation-error-ros-kinetic-in-ubuntu-16-04/58581261#58581261). It guides you through fixing dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same problem. For me, I ran `sudo apt-get install ros-desktop-full` before I realized that is not Melodic. I removed that afterwards but I had the same error when I tried to install with `sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full`.

I think the error came from the fact that I had rospkg 1.1.4 instead of 1.1.7 when I installed `ros_desktop_full`. I did

```
sudo apt-get remove gazebo9* catkin python-rospkg python-rospkg-modules
```

(Here, I also removed `gazebo9` related packages and `catkin` that were installed with `ros-desktop-full`.) Afterwards, I tried to install the melodic desktop full version again and it worked for me.

---

Originally posted by [Catherine Wong](https://answers.ros.org/users/3501/catherine-wong/) with karma: 56 on 2018-08-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-19**:
Just for reference: you probably ran into [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

**Comment by [sonjabrits](https://answers.ros.org/users/33548/sonjabrits/) on 2020-04-21**:
Same happened to me, accidentally first installed `ros-desktop-full`. Your command worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had encountered the same error. I overcome doing the following steps:-

1.This command will remove gazebo9 ,catkin , python-rospkg , python-rospkg-modules packages from your system

`sudo apt-get remove gazebo9* catkin python-rospkg python-rospkg-modules`

2.This command will remove packages from your system, for example, to remove  ros related files:

`sudo apt-get remove ros-*`

3.This command will remove packages and their configuration files.

`sudo apt-get purge ros-*`

4.`sudo apt-get remove ros-melodic-desktop-full`

5.`sudo apt-get purge ros-melodic-desktop-full`

6.This command will remove dependencies that are no longer needed.

`sudo apt-get autoremove`

7.`sudo apt-get install -f`

8.`sudo apt-get update`

9.`sudo apt-get upgrade`

10.Now install ros-melodic-desktop-full

`sudo apt install ros-melodic-desktop-full`

References:[link text](http://ravijo.github.io/ubuntu/)

---

Originally posted by [Neeraj Patil](https://answers.ros.org/users/54427/neeraj-patil/) with karma: 21 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2